can i have a 32bit version of ubuntu 24.04 LTS
my laptop is an old one and i would like to try installing the new version of Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on it, but i just can find the amd64 version of it. it is possible to run it in a 32bit processor? saludos!

The short answer is: you can't. The long answer is: you will have to install an end-of-life release and upgrade from there.

If system is that old, then Ubuntu will not run anyway. Are you sure it is a 32 bit system. Many 64 bit systems had 32 bit Windows. My 2006 BIOS only system was Core2 duo, would not run Ubuntu but would run Kubuntu.
